# Access denied on Directory.CreateDirectory from ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, access-denied, create-directory

In my web application I have a button which creates a folder based on a date, as such:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(SaveLocation + DateTime.Now.Year + @"\" + DateTime.Now.Month + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM") + @"\" + DateTime.Now.Day + @"\" ))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveLocation + DateTime.Now.Year + @"\" + DateTime.Now.Month + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM") + @"\" + DateTime.Now.Day + @"\");
```

When I run this code in localhost, this works fine. Whenever this runs on the server, I get the error:

```
Access to the path '\\server\share\savelocation\2014\06 - June\3\' is denied
```

Things I have tried:

- Site is run under Windows Authentication
- Given the folder and the share read/write permissions to Everyone
- Tried adding `<identity impersonate="true" />` to the Web.config
- Changed Managed Pipeline mode of App Pool to Classic

Why can the application not access this directory?

Comment: It could be to do with the fact that it's connecting to a share, have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671 they might help

Answer (score 2):

You need a physical file path when working with files and folders, not a root-relative path. Try this:
var content = Server.MapPath("~/Content/");

https://forums.asp.net/t/1807775.aspx?Create+e+New+Folder+Access+Denied+

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) [unauthorizedaccessexception](/questions/tagged/unauthorizedaccessexception)

Comment: Exactly the issue for me. I knew something was off the moment I gave access to Everyone but still had permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I disabled Anonymous Authentication to the server and it now works. I assume this was then trying to access the share as a user with insufficient permissions. I didn't pick up on this as it used the correct credentials when passing information to the SQL server, so I assumed the credentials were correct for the folder permissions. But it works now anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the trailing slash; on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the examples does not have it and IIRC it create issues.